# How can you confirm that a problem is open?

Tags: open-problem, research

I was reading an article on Wikipedia and I came across a list of two problems which they asserted to be open, but without citation. I have looked through some literature but not all, as I am afraid I would not exhaust all literature in the field.

I'm wondering if there's some way I can be sure that it is open (or at least provide a source other than wikipedia to confirm that it is indeed open).

The question is not listed on sites like Open Problem Garden either, though I believe this is because it is not very well known.

Thank you!

Comment: I think that you have stumbled on one of the most frustrating open problems  that mathematics researchers have to face.

Comment: Also, if you want to share the actual problems, I'm sure someone on this site is close enough to the field to confirm or deny that is is still open.

Comment: Add a "citation needed" to the Wikipedia article and wait ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's impossible to be *sure* that a problem is open -- certainly it has happened to me that I've published a result only to much later learn part of it was already described in a seemingly unrelated paper in a different field.

Search Google, Google Scholar, the Arxiv, and other paper databases; look for recent survey papers on closely related areas and see if *they* assert the problem is open; ask a trusted and knowledgeable colleague... Those can all increase your confidence (but not prove) the problem is still open.